# Get the post_type of current taxonomy or category page

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I want to get post type of currently visited category or term. As for example, I have post_type **post** and category named **Blog**.

On Blog listing page, how can I get that this is a category of the `post_type` **Post**?

Comment: You can use get_post_type() function http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type

Comment: I already used this function but it don't work when there is no post available :(

Answer (score 0):

Both category and term are **taxonomy**. Taxonomy doesn't have post type. Post type is related to posts/pages/attachments/etc.

When you assign a category to a post, you can't say that that category has or related to specific post type.

If you want to receive post type of the first entity in the query, you will have to do something like this:

```
<?php

// fetch first post from the loop
the_post();

// get post type
$post_type = get_post_type(); 

// rewind the loop posts
rewind_posts();

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, Yes you are right but the case is that i want to get post type.

Comment: @ShaikhAezaz I have updated my answer, maybe it will help you now.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this like

Reference : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type