# rewind_posts() - what actually the use of it, and where using is required or preferred?

Tags: posts, loop

The incomplete [Codex about this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts), says very simply:

> **rewind_posts():**
> Rewind the loop posts.

As per [this WPSE thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110813/get-the-post-type-of-current-taxonomy-or-category-page), with [Eugene Manuilov](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/8170/eugene-manuilov)'s answer, I got:

```
<?php
// fetch first post from the loop
the_post();

// get post type
$post_type = get_post_type(); 

// rewind the loop posts
rewind_posts();
?>
```

With Ian Stewart's theme development tutorial, I found `rewind_posts()`'s use in `archive.php`, `category.php`, `tag.php`, `author.php`:

```
<?php the_post(); ?>
<!-- echo page title -->
<?php rewind_posts(); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <!-- echo content -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

But in TwentyThirteen theme we can't see something like this, but a simple WordPress loop with conditional:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<!-- echo page title -->
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <!-- echo content -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So, I just want to know, while I have the WordPress loop to use, and that works with pagination also, then **where** do I need to REWIND THE LOOP, and **why**?

#### EDIT

Ok, after the first answer, I got a very good article describing the 3 Query-reset functions in WordPress:

> » **[3 Ways to Reset the WordPress Loop](http://digwp.com/2011/09/3-ways-to-reset-the-wordpress-loop/#rewind_posts)** by *Jeff Starr* - DigWP.com

I hope with this the answer can be a lot more educative than currently what we got.

Comment: Please summon the digwp article in your own answer. I really hoped for a much more interesting and educational answer than what we got so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It generally the clears the current loop

```
// main loop
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

// rewind
<?php rewind_posts(); ?>

// new loop
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Here it clears the main loop and start with the new loop

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts

Comment: Some notes: It's _not_ necessary to open and close PHP tags on every line. You might also want to close the `if/endif` at the end. Else you'd trigger the second loop no matter if there're posts or not. Last: Please use the WYSIWYG editor to format your contents.

Comment: Ok. Marked this one as accepted because I found [this digwp post](http://digwp.com/2011/09/3-ways-to-reset-the-wordpress-loop/) helpful with the help of this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Bold caption gave me an instant understanding. Good answer!

Answer (score 1):

It is actually **not necessary** if you use `have_posts()` in the loop since it is called at the end of the loop in said function:

```
public function have_posts() {
    if ( $this->current_post + 1 < $this->post_count ) {
        return true;
    } elseif ( $this->current_post + 1 == $this->post_count && $this->post_count > 0 ) {
        /**
         * Fires once the loop has ended.
         *
         * @since 2.0.0
         *
         * @param WP_Query &$this The WP_Query instance (passed by reference).
         */
        do_action_ref_array( 'loop_end', array( &$this ) );
        // Do some cleaning up after the loop
        $this->rewind_posts();
    }

    $this->in_the_loop = false;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I was looking at the same function and definitely does not seem necessary. I wonder if and old WordPress did not rewind? All of their documentation seems to always showing rewind...